# Stop MouseWheel msgs getting to AutoScroll panel?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, panel, mousewheel, autoscroll

In vb.net I have a user control inherited from Panel which creates it's own embedded `PictureBox`. I want to be able to zoom in on the PictureBox with the mouse wheel, but nothing I do stops the Panel's Vertical `Scrollbar` from processing the msg and panning up after my PictureBox.Size and scrollbar.value assignments.

C# automatically prevents the propagation of the mouse wheel msg to children when you make a Form1 level msg handler. It works perfectly in C# without my having to do anything. (But I despise C#, its not unfriendly, its user hostile...)

So I desperately want to get this issue fixed so I can continue using VB.Net instead banging my head against C#. I have a deadline...

Comment: I just did a quick test and on my system the MouseWheel event was triggered for the Panel and PictureBox in **both** C# and VB.Net (I gave Focus to the PB in the MouseEnter event for the PB and the Panel).  I'm using VS Community Edition 2013.

Comment: Possibly the focus is what accounts for my different behavior. I'll check it out

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I put Me.Focus in the Load method of the Form and the problem went away. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I spoke too soon... It was working until I added more code for drawing on the PictureBox embedded in the Panel. I created a mousewheel handler for the Panel, but a breakpoint in the handler never gets hit. So focus doesn't appear to be the problem.

Comment: If you want to handle the scroll from the panel, then try adding a handler for the PictureBox MouseEnter() event and use Me.Focus() within there.